# Attach a file to a post

Tags: plugin-recommendation, uploads, file-manager

I would like to attach a ZIP file to every post I write on my blog.

I'd like to find a plugin that will do these things:

1- **Insert on the post editor** a box like this which allows me to upload the file.

2- Automatically insert **at the bottom of each post** a box that allows the reader to download the file I attached.

Comment: Why don't you just use the WordPress file uploader?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Do you mean the Wordpress "Add Media" feature? Because when I add certain types of file (e.g.: GPX) it tells me that it can not load them for "security reasons." Moreover, it does not automatically insert at the bottom of each post a box that allows the reader to download the file I attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still use the WordPress uploader, but you'll need to modify it to make it work.  So say you want gpx files (assuming [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) is what you mean).

When you upload something, WordPress looks at it's file extension and based on a set of allowable mime types lets the upload go through or blocks it.  Those allowed mime types are fetched by the function [`get_allowed_mime_types`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types) which, like nearly everything in WordPress, provides a filter to modify things. `upload_mimes` in this case.

We can hook in and allow `.gpx` files.  Mime types are specified in an associative array of `regex_pattern => mime_type` format.

So to add gpx:

```
<?php
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'wpse66651_allow_gpx');
/**
 * Allow the uploading of .gpx files.
 *
 * @param   array $mimes The allowed mime types in file extension => mime format
 * @return  array
 */
function wpse66651_allow_gpx($mimes)
{
    $mimes['gpx'] = 'application/xml';
    return $mimes;
}
```

There are quite a few file types that WordPress recognizes and allows.  If you need more, add them like the above.

As far as auto adding the file links to the content.  That's easy enough.  Hook into `the_content` get the associated attachments, spit them out.

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse66651_display_files');
function wpse66651_display_files($c)
{
    global $post;

    if(!in_the_loop())
        return $c;

    $attachments = get_posts(array(
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'application/xml',
        'nopaging'       => true,
    ));

    if(!$attachments)
        return $c;

    $list = '<ul class="gpx-list">';
    foreach($attachments as $a)
        $list .= '<li>' . wp_get_attachment_link($a->ID) . '</li>';
    $list .= '</ul>';

    return $c . $list;
}
```

The above in a [plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/allow-gpx-files.php).